# Unable to access properties of JSON code through angularJS service

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to access properties of the following JSON structure through AngularJS factory and service methods:

```
{
    "@context": {
        "firstname": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/firstname",
        "lastname": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/lastname"
    },
    "members":[
        {
            "firstname":"Debjit",
            "lastname":"Kumar"
        },
        {
            "firstname":"Hari",
            "lastname":"Haran"
        },
        {
            "firstname":"Kaushik",
            "lastname":"Shrestha"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I am not able retrieve properties of the retrieved JSON object.
The following is my angularJS code:

```
angular.module('rdfa',['ngResource']).config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {controller: RdfaCtrl});
}])
.factory('members', function($resource){
    return $resource('Json.json', {}, { query: {method:'GET', isArray:false} } );
})
.service('jsonservice',function(members){
    this.members=members.query();
});
function RdfaCtrl($scope,jsonservice){
    $scope.members=jsonservice.members.members;
    console.log(jsonservice.members);  // outputs correct JSON structure
    console.log(jsonservice.members.members);  // outputs undefined
    console.log(jsonservice.members['@context']);  // outputs undefined
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making an asynchronous HTTP request, you cannot just simply print the output on the same call cycle. In order to do that you need to add a success callback handler in the `query` action, for example:

```
members.query(function(value) {
  console.log(value); // Resource object
  console.log(value.members); // members object      
  console.log(value['@context']);  // @context object
});
```

Check this plunker for a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/TFlQ6cDkIA3rpjkvHtOA?p=preview